# Best Practice for image link

Tags: html

Just Wondering if some could explain difference between following 4 ways of uses of image in a website.

```
 /img/log.png  (in http://example.com)
 http://example.com/img/log.png
 http://example2.com/img/log.png (Different website on same server)
 http://example3.com/img/log.png (Different website on different server)
```

Performance wise which is the best?

Comment: That's only 2 ways. The first uses a relative address, while 2,3 & 4 are all absolute addresses. It all comes down to the implementation in the browser, so the actual value of the speed difference will vary from browser to browser. In any case, the difference is trivial and not a reason to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a silly question, and that isn't 4 ways of using an image.  So I'll give you a kind of answer.

When referencing an image from within your site just use

```
/img/log.png
```

When referencing images hosted elsewhere

```
//website.com/img/log.png
```

By using the // instead of http:// you will avoid SSL issues.  That is about the only help I can offer.  Other than that, check out some "Learn HTML" sites or books.  Even a quick hour study session should help you move past questions like this.